Fatal Error: You do not have permission to access this page
We are getting this fatal error "You do not have permission to access this page" many times in a day. We are not sure why this is happening.
We are running Civi 5.74.4 Wordpress 6.5.5 Php 8.2.19 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 server
The error Log and debug are as follows
[error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "You do not have permission to access this page."
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#15242
#message: "You do not have permission to access this page."
#code: 0
#file: "/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php"
#line: 584
#cause: null
-_trace: null
-errorData: array:1 [
"error_code" => 0
]
trace: {
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:584 {
CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->permissionDenied()
›   $civicrm_wp_title = ts('You do not have permission to access this page.');
›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception(ts('You do not have permission to access this page.'));
› }
}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:63 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page/View.php:128 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:333 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1231 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:425 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php:565 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp.php:830 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:1336 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/index.php:17 { …}
}
}
]
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(425): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp.php(830): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php(1336): WP->main("")
#9 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/index.php(17): require("/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php")
#11 {main}
Looking on how we can resolve this error and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Perhaps cross-correlate with access logs to see if it's spiders, spambots etc?
